# JPopupMenu and JMenuItem general usage

Tags: java, jmenuitem, jpopupmenu

I have a simple question; I am trying to add a menu to my program. This is what I have thus far:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    JFrame cipherGUIFrame = new CipherGUIFrame();
    cipherGUIFrame.setVisible(true);

    JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();;
    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");
    JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Open");
    JMenuItem save = new JMenuItem("Save");

    JMenuItem cut = new JMenuItem("Cut");
    JMenuItem copy = new JMenuItem("Copy");
    JMenuItem paste = new JMenuItem("Paste");
    JSeparator sep = new JSeparator();
    JMenuItem find = new JMenuItem("Find");
    JPopupMenu options = new JPopupMenu("Options");
    options.setVisible(true);

    file.add(open);
    file.add(save);

    edit.add(cut);
    edit.add(copy);
    edit.add(paste);
    edit.add(sep);
    edit.add(find);
    edit.add(options);

    bar.add(file);
    bar.add(edit);
    cipherGUIFrame.setJMenuBar(bar);
}
```

I am trying to achieve an effect similar to this diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObZKA.jpg .

Is "Options" not the JPopupMenu? It doesn't seem to show up! Or is it simply a JMenuItem and JPopupMenu is the new box that comes up when you hover over it?

Comment: You picture actually suggest you want a `JMenu` within a `JMenu`, not a `JPopupMenu`

Answer (score 0):

A sub menu is just that, a menu which is contained within another menu

Try using something like...

```
JMenu options = new JMenu("Options");
options.add(new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Forward"));
options.add(new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Backward"));
options.addSeparator();
options.add(new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Case Sensetive"));
```

[image: SubMenu]

Take a closer look at [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for more details